# How do I link the data-key attribute of two elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd been following the #javascript30 course in which he links the data-key of a div with the data-key of an audio using javascript and a keydown event as follows

**html**

```
<div data-key = "65" class = "key">
<kbd> A </kbd> <br> <span> Boom </span>
</div>

<audio data-key = "65" src = "sounds/boom.wav" id = "boom"> </audio>
```

**javascript**

```
function playSound(e)
{
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
audio.play();
}
```

Now I want to play the audio when I click on the div but I don't know how to start. I've attempted this, but it says *Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined*. So how do I get it to play the audio on a click event?

**NOTE: I have eight different audio files for eight different divs. Corresponding pairs have the same data-key.**

```
$(".key").click(function()
{
const audio = document.getElementById(`${this.data-key}`)
console.log(audio);
audio.play();
});
```

Comment: You have the function `playSound` that plays the audio, now you just need to call it from your `click` eventListener like `$('.key').click(playSound)`. There are multiple issues with your code that will be figured out as you go further in your learning of Javascript.

Comment: But I have eight different audio files, how do I know which one to play?

Comment: Well, you have to select them by their `data-key`, a single div will play a single audio based on the `data-key` attribute.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, and I don't know how to. 
${this.data-key} doesn't work for me.

Comment: That definitely won't work, but if you don't see why that doesn't work, then I think you're biting off more than you can chew. :)

Comment: Okay I realized that my data-key isn't my ID in the first place. So the function I'm currently using won't work at all. But `const audio = document.querySelector(`${this.data-key}`)` isn't working either?

Comment: @metame with me working three years of javascript since then, you were definitely right in saying i was getting too far ahead of myself then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value of the `data-key` attribute.  Using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which gives you the `${}` syntax in your selector, you can do this using Vanilla JS or jQuery with both examples below.  I'd recommend [reading up on valid DOM selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) as well as basic [dom element attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) access.

A DOM element attribute is not a top-level property of the element. It lives in a `NamedNodeMap` in the `attributes` property of the element.

```js
$(".key").click(function(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${this.attributes['data-key'].value}"]`);
  console.log(audio);
  audio.play();
  // or using jQuery
  // const audio = $(`audio[data-key="${$(this).attr('data-key')');
  // audio[0].play();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="65" class="key">
  <kbd> A </kbd> <br> <span> Boom </span>
</div>

<audio data-key="65" src="http://freewavesamples.com/files/Alesis-Sanctuary-QCard-AcoustcBas-C2.wav" id="boom"> </audio>
```

Comment: Wow this is a really thorough answer. Thanks for the extra links.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple audios, you can use this

```js
$(".key").click(function() {
 var key = $(this).data('key');
 var audio = $('audio[data-key='+key+']');
 audio[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="65" class="key">
  <kbd> A </kbd> <br> <span> Boom </span>
</div>

<audio data-key="65" src="http://freewavesamples.com/files/Alesis-Sanctuary-QCard-AcoustcBas-C2.wav"> </audio>
```

Comment: I have eight different audio files. That's why I didn't directly use this. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, using what's familiar to you use `this.dataset.key` or `$(this).data('key')`:

```js
$(".key").click(function() {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${this.dataset.key}"]`);
  console.log(audio);
  audio.play();
});

function playSound(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="65" class="key">
  <kbd> A </kbd> <br> <span> Boom </span>
</div>

<audio data-key="65" src="sounds/boom.wav" id="boom"> </audio>
```